# Kerberos prevents access to anonymously accessible file

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, iis, kerberos

I am running a .net core web application under IIS. I am using kerberos to authenticate. I am publishing a static file anonymoulsy for a loadbalancer to determine wether the node should be part of the load or not. The problem is that kerberos is preventing me from anonymously accessing the file, even though i've set the permission explicitly to allow anonymously access on the file.

[image: Network traffic]

[image: IIS authentication]

Is it impossbile to access the file anonymously when using kerberos auth?

Comment: Please add your `Starup.cs` and `web.config` files

Comment: The URL (why not end with `Loadbalance/loadbalance.txt`?) does not seem to match your site/files.